# What would be the best way to do a callback within this animation listener?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

In quite a few places, I find myself fading stuff in and out of my application.

I decided to create a helper named Fade.

Fade has a problematic method though:

```
public class Fade {

    public static void hide(final View view, AnimatorListenerAdapter listener) {
        if (view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            view.animate().setDuration(DURATION);
            view.animate().alpha(0f).setListener(listener);
        }
    }

}
```

In order for Fade.hide to work as wanted, I need the `AnimationListenerAdapter` to do the following in it's `onAnimationEnd` method. Note, the reason I don't just do this is because the person using this helper should be able to customize listeners for when fading begins, ends, etc.

```
view.setAlpha(1f);
view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
view.animate().setListener(null);
```

where the `view` references the View being used on the client side of this helper.

I think this behavior is extremely undesirable and has made me question if it is even worth having the helper.

I can't just have the person using the helper pass in an AnimatorListenerAdapter, which I then stuff into my own AnimatorListenerAdapter somehow.

I thought of doing the following, but it is definitely hacky:

```
public static void hide(final View view, Runnable endAction) {
    if (view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        view.animate().setDuration(DURATION);
        view.animate().alpha(0f).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                view.setAlpha(1f);
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                view.animate().setListener(null);

                endAction.run();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

This seems very hacky and ultimately would require me to make many method signatures to account for all the `AnimatorListenerAdapter` callbacks like onAnimationRepeat, onAnimationStart, etc.

Is there anyway to mitigate this, or should I cut the code-smell and just create the same methods in whatever classes do lots of fading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is have a compositing `AnimatorListenerAdapter` that wraps the provided listener and delegates the calls after doing the required work. For example:

```
public final class FadeHelper {
    public static void fade(final View view, Animator.AnimatorListener listener) {
        if (view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

            // Create a composite listener and override onAnimationEnd()
            // to do your own thing, then call through to super to pass
            // the event to the provided listener.
            final Animator.AnimatorListener compositeListener = new CompositeAnimatorListenerAdapter(listener) {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                    view.setAlpha(1f);
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    // Not sure why this line is necessary?
                    view.animate().setListener(null);

                    // This passes the event to the original listener
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animator);
                }
            });

            view.animate()
                .setDuration(DURATION)
                .alpha(0f)
                .setListener(compositeListener);
        }
    }

    private static class CompositeAnimatorListenerAdapter implements Animator.AnimatorListener {
        private final Animator.AnimatorListener mDelegate;

        public CompositeAnimatorListenerAdapter(Animator.AnimatorListener delegate) {
            mDelegate = delegate;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
            if (mDelegate != null) {
                mDelegate.onAnimationStart(animator);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            if (mDelegate != null) {
                mDelegate.onAnimationEnd(animator);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
            if (mDelegate != null) {
                mDelegate.onAnimationCancel(animator);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
            if (mDelegate != null) {
                mDelegate.onAnimationRepeat(animator);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **I can't just have the person using the helper pass in an AnimatorListenerAdapter, which I then stuff into my own AnimatorListenerAdapter somehow.** This is exactly what I wanted to achieve, but didn't think it through. I guess in hindsight, it wasn't as difficult as my mind made it. I'll try putting this to use right away.

Comment: If you want to edit your answer, the correct implementation has `Animator animation` instead of `Animation animation` as the parameter in all the overridden methods.